# how to count the site current visitors using java script or php

Tags: php, javascript, visitor-statistic, visitors

I need to get the current site visitors number using Javascript or PHP.

I need it using the best way between php and Javascript.

Comment: Honestly, have you tried searching at all? Can you give some more specifics?

Comment: i need to get the current site visitors count using the best way between javascript and php

Comment: Google Analytics is your friend! (http://www.google.com/analytics)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following link is a blog post regarding a  widget that will allow you to use PHP, MySQL and JavaScript/jQuery. It might be able to point you in the right direction for what you need, and features a tutorial on implementing it.

[Who Is Online Widget](http://www.neurosoftware.ro/programming-blog/facebook-web-design/tutorial/%E2%80%9Cwho-is-online%E2%80%9D-widget-with-php-mysql-jquery/)

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Hope it gave you something that you could use.

Comment: this may be the article: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/who-is-online-widget-php-mysql-jquery/

Answer (score 2):

Here is another great tutorial that might help you out:

http://inobscuro.com/tutorials/simple-php-unique-visitors-counter-30/

Good will coding...

Comment: dead link. "Page not found"