# synchronous issue of Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics-api

I want to show information to every web site visitors about 
 how many user are currently using my web sites at my web site's home page.
So now, i am testing **Google Analytic API**.
But I still wondering that could this API support information which is so synchronous.
I am not so sure about that. 
 That may be I am just beginner for this API.

Let me give sample event which I testing right now.

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html

Upper link is which i am testing.

With such parameters ..
dimensions value 

**ga:browser,ga:browserVersion,ga:city,ga:hour,ga:day**
metrics value 

**ga:entrances**

I get such result...

```
Chrome  14.0.835.202    CityName    10  19  1
Chrome  14.0.835.202    CityName    11  19  1
Internet Explorer   8.0 CityName    10  19  1
Safari  533.21.1    CityName    11  19  1
```

Safari result row only show after 15 minutes long from when i start using that browser and my web site.
It take too long to display current result.

So I have a worry about synchronous issue for this API.
Every suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics does not provide real time information.  If you want to show users real time information about the number of users currently on your site, you'll have to use a different system.

Comment: thank for your suggestion @Brian Fisher, So is there any proper solution ? If so let me know that.

Comment: Check out this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649926/how-to-count-the-site-current-visitors-using-java-script-or-php

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics has just begun offering real time analytics, but it is still an invite only service. Here is a link to page where you can request an invitation:

https://services.google.com/fb/forms/realtimeanalytics/

However, it doesn't look like any of the real time data is accessible through the API yet, so you may want to put your project off for several months while our friends at Google get that API built or look for a different solution, like [Chartbeat's API](http://chartbeat.pbworks.com/w/page/15588401/FrontPage).